# Unset SendEnv option in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, locale

Accordingly to *ssh* man page *-o* allows to set the content of a given ssh client option. I would like to unset SendEnv (or set it to empty) in order to avoid locale setup in server side.

I got the desired effect by commenting SendEnv line in ssh_config file. However, it is not a good option for my application.

How to achieve this when running ssh command? I tried `ssh -o SendEnv='' server` without success.

Comment: This could help you : http://superuser.com/questions/485569/how-to-disable-sendenv-variables-set-in-ssh-config-from-ssh-config

Comment: Thank you @EricDuminil. However, in that answer I would need access to server machine as superuser to edit AcceptEnv entry in sshd_config. What I look for is a way to avoid changing sshd_config and ssh_config too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do that on the command-line. The `SendEnv` option does not overwrite, but append to the existing values.

But you can create a different configuration file, which will not have these options and use `-F` option, which will prevent using the global configuration file:

```
ssh -F /my/specific_ssh_config server
```

Answer (score 0):

By putting together the two previous answers, this should work:

```
echo "Include config SendEnv -*" > /tmp/foo && ssh -F /tmp/foo server
```

(If anyone can shorten it, please edit.)

`SendEnv -*` can't be used effectively as an argument to `-o` because command line SSH options are applied first, with user/system configuration applied only afterwards. So, `-o SendEnv -*` would normally nothing to override, and we instead provide the override in a temporary configuration file based on the user's `~/.ssh/config` file.

Or, if you don't mind dropping all user/system SSH configuration (including existing `SendEnv` declarations), then

```
ssh -F /dev/null server
```

works fine too.

Answer (score -1):

A bit late but maybe someone can still profit from my answer. According to 'man ssh_config' it is possible to clear SendEnv variables:

> It is possible to clear previously set SendEnv variable names by prefixing patterns with -.

So you should basically be able to use your construct with

```
-o SendEnv=''
```

But instead of leaving the brackets empty you put the variables which you want to overwrite in the brackets but prefix each of them with a dash.

Or you specify the same in your users own ssh config (usually ~/.ssh/config). Wich if I understand the documentation correctly should also overwrite it.

Comment: You should, but it doesn't work. (I just tested this again, on Ubunu 18.04.)